# error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/readingcom.git'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

`! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)`

I have been trying to deploy this app from git repo oh heroku but pre-receive hook declined error keeps popping

enter code here

```
remote: sh: 1: react-scripts: Permission denied
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 126
remote: npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 126
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.SgBaJ/_logs/2020-06-19T18_16_40_663Z-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 126
remote: npm ERR! readingcom@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 126
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the readingcom@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.SgBaJ/_logs/2020-06-19T18_16_40_679Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:
remote:        - node_modules checked into source control
remote:          https://blog.heroku.com/node-habits-2016#9-only-git-the-important-bits
remote:
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to readingcom.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/readingcom.git
 ! [remote rejected]   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/readingcom.git'
```

The app is a MERN stack app. I have checked and updated my dependencies, heroku CLI etc.

Comment: Try this:
$npm install react-scripts --save and then run your application

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into similar problem. I just created a production build with "npm run build"....and then pushed the node app with the build folder...

configured this in node app

```js
app.get('*',(req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile('path to build/index.html');
})
```

pushed on heroku and it worked...It is kinda hacky approach, doesn't really solve the problem, but if you are in hurry, can give it a try

Comment: I have this line in my server.js file. Its a MERN stack app

```
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // Set static folder
    app.use(express.static('client/build'))
  
    app.get('*', (req, res) =>
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
    )
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, what I meant was run "npm run build", a build folder will be created, git track that build folder, remove the heroku post scripts from package.json  and push on heroku master

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried what you said, the deployment was successful but its but the app url is showing 'not found'

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem today ...

In my research I had to have a lot of answers which solve one point but not all ...

Finally, re-reading the error I received, I noticed that the collectstatic was the first error notified,

> error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.

and since it was a manually doable query, I did it manually with the following code

```
./manage.py collectstatic
```

(for this command line to work, you must specify the STATIC_ROOT in setting.py)

*setting.py*

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join (BASE_DIR, 'my_static_app_folderName/static')
```

afterwards, you must disable the automatic execution of this request during deployment with the command line

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC = 1
```

(for heroku users)

then relaunch

```
git push heroku master
```

it should work ...

Answer (score 0):

another way....

you can check your git status with

```
$ git status
```

if you have an folder which has to be check by git in

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .gitignore
        Procfile
```

or in

```
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   store/settings.py
```

you have to do

```
$ git add store/
$ git add Procfile
```

for each files and folder in those sections, except the file .gitignore...
After that, you check again with

```
$ git status
```

if everything is ok, now you can do

```
$ git commit -m "Launching to production"
```

to apply git adds...

Verify your app config with

```
$ heroku config
```

than try again

```
$ git push heroku master
```

hope, it'll work !!!

*Excuse for my english level*

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue whilst trying to deploy a create-react-app to heroku.
It was caused by me accidentally committing the `node_modules` folder to my git repository. 
Problem was solved by

- running `git rm -r --cached node_modules`
- adding `node_modules/` to `.gitignore` file
- commit changes again and run `git push heroku master`